# How was this principal normal vector equation simplified?

Tags: calculus, parametric

I can't seem to figure out what to do.

$$T'(t)=-\frac{1}{2}(4t^2+1)^{-3/2}8t(2t{i}+{j})+(4t^2+1)^{-1/2}2{i} = 2(4t^2+1)^{-3/2}\big({i}-2t{j}\big)$$

I don't understand how half the equation seems to just disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{equation} \label{eq1}
\begin{split}
T'(t)&=-\frac{1}{2}(4t^2+1)^{-3/2}8t(2t{i}+{j})+(4t^2+1)^{-1/2}2{i} \\
 & = -\frac{1}{2}(4t^2+1)^{-3/2}8t(2t{i}+{j})+(4t^2+1)(4t^2+1)^{-3/2}2{i}\\
 & = (4t^2+1)^{-3/2}\big(-4t(2t{i}+{j})+(4t^2+1)2{i}\big) \\
 & = (4t^2+1)^{-3/2}\big(-8t^2{i}-4t{j}+8t^2{i}+2{i}\big) \\
 & = (4t^2+1)^{-3/2}\big(-4t{j}+2{i}\big) \\
 & = 2(4t^2+1)^{-3/2}\big({i}-2t{j}\big)
\end{split}
\end{equation}